# How to generate array in PHP?

Tags: php

I am generate PHP array like this:

```
$val = array("request"=>array(
                    "First Name"=>'xxxx',
                    "Last NAme"=>'xxx',
                    "yourAddress"=>array(
                            "Address" => array(
                                "City" => 'abc',
                                "State" => 'xyz',
                            ),
                            "Address" => array(
                                "City" => 'def',
                                "State" => 'hij',
                            ),
                    )
            ));
```

But when I run this array at that time **yourAddress** array overwrite and it return only last value like **def** and **hij**. I need both value and array key like **Address** also print.

Is it possible?

Comment: Read about [arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/book.array.php) in the PHP manual.

Comment: Pray tell, how can an array contain **the same key twice**?! How would you expect that to work? You probably just want no key (implicit numeric keys) there.

Comment: Just noticed that you've rolled back a change I made on 6th November. I've reverted your change, since mine was correct, and if I catch you doing that again you will get a moderator flag. I have also downvoted this question. Please note that requests for urgency do not belong in questions - your question is not more important than others here, and in any case on an old question, it is redundant.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays can't have the same key twice, they need to be unique. What you can do however, is this:

```
$val = array(
    "request" => array(
        "First Name" => 'xxxx',
        "Last NAme" => 'xxx',
        "yourAddress" => array(
            "Address" => array(
                array(
                    "City" => 'abc',
                    "State" => 'xyz',
                ),
                array(
                    "City" => 'def',
                    "State" => 'hij',
                )
            ),
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the same keys. The best solution would be to use an index:

```
$val = array("request"=>array(
    "First Name"=>'xxxx',
    "Last NAme"=>'xxx',
    "yourAddress"=>array(
        array(
            "City" => 'abc',
            "State" => 'xyz',
        ),
        array(
            "City" => 'def',
            "State" => 'hij',
        ),
    )
));
```

Then you can get the value with $val['request']['yourAddress'][0];

Comment: I use one wsdl services.it is not accepted 0 and 1 index of array. it accept same key array.

Comment: Is it an option to use ['address1'] and ['address2']?

Comment: it is use like [address] and [address].

Comment: Well, that's simply not possible because the same key is used twice, it will be overwritten.

Comment: yes, that's the problem. IS [address] and [address] possible for any way?

Comment: As I said, that's not possible. The solution is in my answer. If the service won't accept that, I think it doesn't accept multiple addresses.

Comment: @PHPDeveloper Are you trying to generate XML with two consecutive `<address>` elements? Then you'll have to do that through an XML generator API directly, or you need some specific converter which can convert your array accordingly. You simply cannot express the same data structure using a PHP array.